# Formal alternative to "that'll do"

Tags: phrases, synonyms, formality, do

I use "that'll do" in circumstances where I acknowledge *that* something is sufficient.

What is a formal alternative for this phrase, that can take place in a formal letter or a conversation ?

Context:

There's a party that asked for a couple of screenshots from my PC. I have the screenshots but due to a technical limit it may not be enough.

My sentence:

Attached are the screenshots you requested. *Explanation for technical stuff.* **Hope that'll do.** OR **Will that do?**

Thanks,

Comment: *Enough*, *ample*, *adequate*, *serves (the purpose)*, *sufficient*, ... Will that do?

Comment: :) It's a formal question actually, so I opted for _will it suffice ?_ Hope it will

Comment: Please provide the sentence.

Comment: If you are not delivering what you promised, you need to own your failure. “Hoping that it will do” is offensive to the person who was let down, and they’ll remember it longer than you think.

Comment: The only thing that makes *that'll do* immediately informal is the contraction. I see nothing obviously informal about *that will do*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more formal way of expressing such could be: ... **that will suffice**.

The idiom **that will do** has in its definition a more formal synonym: [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/that+will+do)

> That is enough, that will **suffice**.

to suffice:  [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/193537?redirectedFrom=suffice#eid)

> To be enough, sufficient, or adequate for a purpose or the end in
>   view.

As in:

> New York Times Aug 22, 2019 Just a bowl of it with a dab of yogurt
>   **would suffice** [will do], but for the full effect it should be topped with a
>   savory stew of chicken or lamb.

Suffice comes from a combination of the Latin words sub ("under") and facere ("make") that together mean "meet the need of." This need is usually the bare minimum — sufficient!

Answer (score 3):

The problem with "That'll do." and "Will that do?" is *not* that they are informal, but that they may be considered condescending, rude, or impatient.

As a statement of acknowledgement, a simple thanks should suffice.

- Thank you for [completing my request for _____].

As a question, it may be dropped entirely from your sample statement.

- Attached are the screenshots you requested. [Explanation for technical stuff.]

If you wish to add an interpersonal touch, you may use something like the following:

- I hope this resolves _____. Please let me know if there is anything else I can do for you.

Also, do not end the letter with "Thanks". Not only is the word informal, the other party has not done anything for which you should thank them. The traditional closing is "Sincerely".

Comment: Thank you for the input, actually the _Thanks_ was for you guys :) I wouldn't use such phrase in a formal letter as well.